# Loading thepiratebay npm-module client-side using Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I have a node.js server file that loads my site and runs javascript without any issues.
I have added `tpb = require('thepiratebay');` to my server.js file and it works fine with the below example in the server file:

```
tpb.search('Game of Thrones', {
category: '205'
}).then(function(results){
console.log(results);
}).catch(function(err){
console.log(err);
});
```

I tried using the same code in my html page. In the console I got:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"
```

So I tried using the `browserify` module by bundling a simple file with `var tpb = require('thepiratebay');` in.

I then called the bundle.js file in my html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

But when I try and use the example code `tpb.search('Game of Throne...etc`I get

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: tpb is not defined"
```

Is it possible to browserify thepiratebay and if so why wont it recognise `tpb.search...etc` in my html code?

Comment: Could you paste the code snippet how you try it exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting tpb.search in your server-side code and attach it to the onclick event of a button before you browserify it.

Browserify works by using closures to create scopes. The tbp library and its search function is inaccessible from the global scope, which is where your client-side code is trying to call it.